# jQuery.contains() does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I should get an "alert" in the following case, but I am not getting any "alert". I am trying a simple example of `jQuery.Contains()`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var alpha = $.contains('body','p') {
                    alert(alpha);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) the API takes only element nodes (not JavaScript/jQuery *objects* or *selectors*)

> Check to see if a **DOM element** is a descendant of another **DOM element**.
>
> Only element nodes are supported; if the second argument is a text or
>   comment node, $.contains() will return false.
>
> **Note:** The first argument must be a DOM element, not a jQuery object or plain JavaScript object.

you should change the code to

```
$(function () {
   alert($.contains(document.body, $("p")[0])) //alerts true
   alert($.contains(document.body, document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]));    //alerts true
})
```

Comment: It still not making alert! ;(

Comment: Can you help me with plunker? I tried but still stuck on this with no alerts!

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery.contains** only returns **boolean** and doe not have a callback.
Try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($.contains(document.body,$('p')[0]));
});
```

Comment: `alpha` will always be false, since it accepts DOM nodes and not text

Comment: I mean only DOM Elements and not CSS/jQuery selectors

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var alpha = $.contains(document.body,$("p")[0])
    if (alpha) {
         alert(alpha);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/en55xfhL/)

> Arguments are always DOM elements, not simple text.

For more details, see [this.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

Comment: Answers are always better if they contain an explanation, not just code or external references.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, got it ,,

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code you have error on this line (var alpha = $.contains('body','p'){)
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var alpha = $.contains('body','p');
alert(alpha);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code also doesn't work since you have provided an incorrect API usage

Comment: @Sourabh I don't know about what _over smart_ you are talking about, but [jQuery.contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) takes `DOM Element`s as arguments, not `String`s. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLamxc27/) with your incorrect code.