# jQuery contains() not working

Tags: jquery

Why is the following jQuery line not working?

```
$( '.variation-Billing:contains( "Once Off" )' ).fadeOut(0);
```

Markup:

```
<dd class="variation-Billing"><p>Once Off</p>
</dd>
```

Comment: Did you happen to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691398/jquery-contains-does-not-work-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra spaces in [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('.variation-Billing:contains("Once Off")').fadeOut(0);
```

> As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks.

So the following also works:

```
$('.variation-Billing:contains(Once Off)').fadeOut(0);
```

But it seems to get mad if you put spaces outside of the quotes

Full example

```js
$('.variation-Billing:contains("Once Off")').fadeOut(1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dd class="variation-Billing">
  <p>Once Off</p>
</dd>
```

Comment: Thanks! I find it quite weird that extra spaces there break the function... Like it sounds like a bug!